# How to find the pixel value from latlng of static map?

Tags: javascript

I have tried to find out the pixel value of a map to rendering the external element on static map. I have refered with the below link, but it is not working fine for me.
[Getting pixel coordinated from google static maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898964/getting-pixel-coordinated-from-google-static-maps)

Could you suggest me the any other answer regarding this?

[Getting pixel coordinated from google static maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898964/getting-pixel-coordinated-from-google-static-maps)

Comment: are you using Java or JavaScript? The question you linked uses Java... Also, provide some code you have tried.

Comment: yes I have tried with javascript. But I couldn`t get the exact location of X and Y, for corresponding lat and long value. Could you guide me to found this

Comment: What language do you want to use? Have you only tried JavaScript? If so, what did code did you use?

Comment: http://scilabipcv.tritytech.com/2017/11/01/plotting-google-static-maps/                      I have using this logic in my JS code. Is this right or wrong?

Comment: So you are using the program Scilab? If you are, just copy and paste the code into your Scilab project, or however it works.

Comment: Not copy and paste. Just understand the logic and apply it in my JS code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200849/discussion-between-arun-r-and-rojo).